# microservice testing : in-process component(individual micro-service) testing

Tags: testing, microservices

I am exploring individual microservice testing & came across a good guide https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservice-testing/#testing-component-in-process-diagram. This post suggest there is a way to test the individual microservices "in-process".

Which means the test & service will execute in same process, it also provides the lib which can be used. However I am not able to understand following things
1) How exactly "in-process" testing will work in microservice architecture
2) Any pointers on how to use "inproctester" lib.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by hosting your API in process, interacting with it - in process -  whilst using test doubles at  the edges of you API,  or (put another way) using test doubles for external collaborators.

This allows an API (and its core behaviour) to be tested in a test (unit/integration depending on opinion) without ever hitting a network or database or filesystem.

This testing will provide coverage but obviously not all the coverage you need

In .NET core you can use `TestServer` included in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost package.

If your API is simple enough you can perhaps reduce your types of testing (N.B. I am not suggesting reducing coverage)
This approach is alluded to in the slide deck you mention on page 8/25

Paraphrasing. If the logic in the API is small, component tests may be favourable to isolated and sociable unit tests

This approach is also recommended in the Spotify "Honeycomb" style testing.  They call component testing of an API Integration testing (which coincidentally Microsoft also call it when they are using TestServer in their tests (second link for concrete examples)

- https://labs.spotify.com/2018/01/11/testing-of-microservices/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing

I think that the thrust of the approach (regardless of its specific name)  is that in process testing is fast and external collaborators are replaed with test doubles.

One thing worth noting is that "out of process" component tests are basically end to end tests but with all external collaborators swapped out with test doubles.

These may be a bit slower than  in process component tests but exercise a bit more of the "stack".  I'd suggest that if you are going to end-end test anyway,  I'd try and do in process component testing as much as possible.

Comment: These were valuable inputs.I am not able to clearly differentiate between "Component" and "Integration" test as both are dependent on Stubs/Mocks

Comment: In this scenario, the component is your core application.  Integration tests would cover your adapters (think hexagonal architecture) Besides,   Integration test is such an overloaded term. If you think about it, a component test IS an integration test.  Almost everything is an integration test.  Where  I work atm, we -  however -  specifically call tests of commands, queries against a persistence store (eg a database) integration tests.  Its a shame some terms arent standardized  but as long as consensus (on your project) is met about R&Rs things should be clearer.

Comment: R&Rs, what am I going on about?... That was roles and responsibilities. Overloaded?? What..Basically... the same name-  Integration tests - is used and can be used for testing at unit, externally and end to end....over and out